# How to compare two CSV files with different header rows and remove duplicates from the first one?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files. The first one contains the following headers and data:

```
Name,Email,OfficePhone
Bill,Bill@jump.com,123-456-7890
```

The second one contains just:

```
primaryEmail
Bill@jump.com
```

I would like to compare the two and remove any duplicate rows from the first file where the email in the first file exists in the second one. I'm trying to use `compare-object`, but not sure where to go from here.

```
$File1 = Import-Csv C:\it\newuser.csv
$File2 = Import-Csv C:\it\email.csv

Compare-Object $File1 $File2 -Property email
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably just fetching the primary emails first from the 2nd CSV, then using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) to filter out duplicate rows with duplicate emails from the 1st CSV.

```
# Get primary emails from 2nd CSV
$csv2 = (Import-Csv -Path .\2.csv).primaryEmail

# Remove rows from 1st csv that don't have an email in $csv2
$removedDuplicateRows = Import-Csv -Path .\1.csv | Where-Object {$_.Email -notin $csv2}

# Export filtered rows into output.csv
$removedDuplicateRows | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If your header column has quotes around it, then you need to include those quotes (e.g. `.primaryEmail` becomes `."primaryEmail"`).

If you're using PowerShell 7, you can use `-UseQuotes Never` from [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) to not include quotes in your output CSV.

Answer (score 2):

[RoadRunner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091355/45375) offers an effective solution.

However, with large input sets **performance can become a concern**, because a linear search of the array of email addresses (`$csv2`) is performed *for every CSV input row*.

Using [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) offers a solution, because lookups in hash sets are consistently fast.

The [`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet) method offers a convenient way to construct such a hash set from an object implementing [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable-1), such as an array.

```
# Build a case-insensitive hash set of email addresses from $File2 
# whose elements are to be excluded from $File1.
# Note that the cast to [string[]] is required in order for PowerShell
# to find the right generic method overload.
$refEmailsHashSet = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToHashSet(
  [string[]] (Import-Csv $File2).primaryEmail,
  [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
)

# Import $File1 and filter out the email addresses from $File2
# Pipe to `Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ...` to save to a new CSV file.
Import-Csv $File1 | Where-Object { -not $refEmailsHashSet.Contains($_.Email) }
```

An additional - somewhat obscure - way to improve performance is to work around the inefficient implementation of the `Where-Object` (and `ForEach-Object`) cmdlet, as of PowerShell 7.2, as discussed in [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982)

```
# Works the same as above, with faster alternative to Where-Object
Import-Csv $File1 | 
  & { process { if (-not $refEmailsHashSet.Contains($_.Email)) { $_ } } }
```

Note that this independent optimization, which can equally be applied to the linear-lookup `-notin` solution in RoadRunner's answer, has the largest impact on performance overall.

Comment: About how much qualifies as "large" here, in your experience? Thousand? Tens of thousands? Etc.?

Comment: @TylerH, that is hard to quantify, given the many variables, including hardware speed. The higher the combined row count (esp. in file 2), the larger the performance improvement that this solution achieves. Conversely, for small row counts the optimization may slow things down (but that won't matter in absolute terms). A quick test with 100 (file 2) / 10,000 (file 1) rows with 3 columns each resulted in a 25% speed-up on my Mac. YMMV. Also note the additional optimization (which can be applied independently) I've added to the answer.